# Placement of currency symbols: before or after numeric amount and with or without a separating space?

Tags: numbers

In Italian, out of the four choices given below, what is the proper / standard way of formatting a currency amount (does the currency symbol go before or after the amount and should there be a separating space between the currency symbol and the amount)?

1. 300 €
2. € 300
3. 300€
4. €300

Thanks.

---

NOTE: My question is related to [this one](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/5674/what-is-the-correct-way-to-format-currency-in-italian) but goes beyond that question as I am also asking about the spacing between the currency symbol and the numeric amount.

Comment: ...and even there it was observed that this “has little to do with the Italian language”, and more with international conventions and anti-counterfeit measures.

Comment: Hi @JohnSonderson. Thanks for asking, but details about adding a space could not prevent this question from being an exact duplicate. If you follow the links in the accepted answer to [that question](http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/5674/what-is-the-correct-way-to-format-currency-in-italian), you'd find all the recommendations about writing the symbols correctly (spacing included).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Italian you can write

> 1.300,00 €

or

> € 1.300,00

Normally, people make use of the first of these two formats. You must add a space between the number and the currency symbol, you must use a period (".") to group digits as in

> 1.300 €

and you must use a comma (",") before the start of the decimal part of a numeric amount. Normally, for currency in euros, two digits are written for the fractional part.